# When finding a MacLaurin polynomial do i really need to do all derivatives?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I've been faced with the following function $1/(1-x)$ and i need  the MacLaurin  n = 7 , i am supposed to derivate it 7 times?  Or am i missing something, it seems kinda exhausting to do them all or my way of derivating it is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want derivatives, then you can note that they are, starting with the function itself

$$\frac{1}{1-x},\frac{1}{(1-x)^2},\frac{2}{(1-x)^3},\frac{6}{(1-x)^4},\frac{24}{(1-x)^5},\frac{120}{(1-x)^6},\ldots,\frac{n!}{(1-x)^n},\ldots$$

Substituting $x=0$ you get the sequence $1,1,2,6,\ldots,n!,\ldots$

Plugging this into the formula gives the expansion

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+O(x^7)$$

Hope this helps

Comment: Given that the OP was assigned this as a problem, the OP more than likely has not been exposed to the sum of a geometric series formula and the assignment appears to be to give the OP the very intuition as to why that formula is correct to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: That derivative should have a pattern that you can utilize for evaluating it at a point. Find the first couple derivatives, and the pattern should be pretty easy to pick up on. Otherwise, brute force it.